# variables post in koa framework

Tags: koa

hi where is the data in post call in koa without co-body or bodyparse or why this error

Error: invalid JSON, only supports object and array
     at parse (d:\Proyectos\koaJsTest\node_modules\co-body\lib\json.js:56:13)

Answer (score 0):

co-body performs this regex unless the "strict" option is set to false:

```
/^[\x20\x09\x0a\x0d]*(\[|\{)/
```

Perhaps your json is making it to co-body as a URL-encoded string?

Answer (score 0):

Its either going to be the format of the JSON that you are uploading if you are setting the `Content-Type` to `application/json`.

Otherwise, may be using the wrong `Content-Type`. For example if you were uploading files where the `Content-Type` should be `multipart/form-data` but you accidentally set the `Content-Type` to `application/json` when it should you would see this error.

This has tripped me up in the past.